# make thumbnail view the default with native file manager

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

My client has complained that when they want to choose an image for a channel with an image filed they are given the list of file names by default.

They would find it more intuitive to show the thumbnail view by default rather than need to change the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Open up ee_filebrowser.js and search for the first instance of a("#dir_choice").val(). Immediately after that add this:

```
; a("#view_type").val('thumb').change();
```

Make sure you include the leading ;.